Oxidation of Toluene with Permanganate in Acidic and Basic Environment
So, in my current undergrad organic chemistry course, we were introduced to oxidation using permanganate. I know that alkenes can be oxidised to carbonyl compounds using hot, acidic KMnO4, but in our lab sessions, we oxidised toluene to benzoic acid using basic KMnO4.One of our lab instructors asked us why we needed to use basic permanganate for aromatic oxidations. After looking through numerous answers on this website and referring to standard OChem textbooks, I still do not know the answer to this specific question. In fact, I know that acidic permanganate should actually have a higher oxidising power in acidic media because it gains 5 electrons to go from Mn(VII) to Mn(II); in basic media, it gains 3 electrons to go from Mn(VII) to Mn(IV).
The only possible explanation that came to my mind is that in a basic medium (as used in the toluene oxidation) is that permanganate gets reduced to its Mn(VI) state: K2MnO4, with the generation of oxygen in situ, whereas this does not happen in acidic media. I proposed this reason to my lab instructor, but they said that while it did have something to do with the answer, it was not the answer. So I reach out for help here: why, in the oxidation of aromatic compounds like toluene, do we use basic permanganate, even though acidic permanganate should be a better oxidising agent?

It is controlling reaction rates. the oxidation requires Hydrogen ions. Acidic permanganate will oxidize almost anything. Do aqueous permanganate oxidations actually generate O2?

Consider the desired product -- what would happen should oxidation go further??

To @jimchmst, thank you for your response: could you elaborate more on “controlling reaction rates?” If the oxidation requires hydrogen ions, wouldn’t a mildly acidic environment be better? As for aqueous MnO4 oxidations: the production of oxygen seems to be observed, at least according to some inorganic textbooks (inorganic syntheses, vol. 11, pp. 56) — how true or generalisable this is, I am not sure of. I did see another answer on here that claimed that the Mn(VI) produced in alkaline medium is responsible for benzylic hydrogen abstraction, perhaps this could have something to do with it?

Yes acidic is better if that is what is wanted; usually permanganate and chromate oxidations have to be controlled. acidity is one method. Permanganate to manganate can happen by reduction or decomposition. With a good reducing agent reduction is probably favored. The O2 mechanism requires some investigation

To @DrMoishePippik, thank you for the response: I would assume that if the oxidation were to go further, it would end up being a decarboxylation. I would in turn ask (and please, pardon my inexperience here) if this decarboxylation is even possible if we were to do it under mild acid conditions (i.e., would decarboxylation happen in ANY kind of acidic environment?), which would still make Mn a stronger oxidising agent as compared to its activity in basic environments -- which still leaves me with my original question on why we perform this under (relatively) strong basic conditions.

Thanks @jimchmst. I believe Dr. Moishe Pippik was eluding to the same idea: if benzoic acid kept being oxidised (as it may be in acidic environments), a decarboxylation would occur. I know when we oxidise alkenes to diols with acidic permanganate, an excess amount of permanganate would result in cleavage of the diol to the carbonyl compounds (aldehydes/ketones) -- does the same apply to aromatic systems? I know these kinds of decarboxylations require some harsh conditions (soda lime + temperatures well over 100C). The present oxidation is happing at much lower temperatures, ≈ 75-80C.

@peregrine_sid, acid (or even neutral) permanganate is a strong-enough oxidizer to set fire to glycols -- permanganate-glycol "bombs" are used by foresters to make back-fires from an airplane. End product: CO2 + H2O.

@DrMoishePippik, I did not know that! It is definitely about control then. Thank you.
